# How can I set the width of a reportElement using propertyExpression in Jasper Reports

Tags: jasper-reports

```xml
<reportElement x="79" y="103" width="279" height="23" backcolor="#000000">
    <propertyExpression name="width"><![CDATA["100"]]></propertyExpression>
</reportElement>
```

I am trying to set the width of a ***reportElement*** by using a ***propertyExpresssion***, *JasperReports* is picking up the width as 279 instead of 100 in the code above, and if I remove the width attribute in the ***reportElement*** tag I will get an error.

What am I doing wrong? It compiles, fills and all, but the width in the expression is not being used.

Answer (score 0):

```
JRElement element = jasperReport.getTitle().getElementByKey("graphWidthKey");
element.setWidth(100);
```

Comment: I am looking for a jrxml solution to the example I have in my question, not a java version.

Answer (score 0):

why not directly set 100 at reportElement tag, and i doubt whether is a solution to have width of text inside a box different of the box width. if you know, please share.

Answer (score 0):

`propertyExpression` can **not** be used to set **width** that is an `attribute`. They are used to add property's for example during export or to pass value to a `ChartCustomizer`

These are the available properties for configuration [jasper report properties](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html)

A typical property would be

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row" value="true"/>
```

And you can create a `propertyExpression` for this:

```
<propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row"><![CDATA[$V{timeToBreak}?"true":"false"]]></propertyExpression>
```